# Roman numerals to decimal

Tags: c++, homework, converting, roman-numerals

This is a program for converting Roman numerals to their decimal equivalents. There must be a better way of distinguishing between, for example, 'IV' and 'VI', than what I have currently written.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


class romanType{
public:
    romanType();
    romanType(string s);
    ~romanType();

        void setRoman(string); //Set the Roman numeral from user entries.
        int romanToDecimal(); //Convert the Roman numeral(string) to Decimal value.
        void printDecimal(); //Display the decimal value.
        void printRoman(); //Display the Roman numeral value.
private:
    string romanNum;
    int decimalNum = 0;

};

romanType::romanType()
{
    romanNum = 1;
}

romanType::~romanType()
{
}

void romanType::setRoman(string troll)
{
    romanNum = troll;
}

int romanType::romanToDecimal()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < romanNum.length(); i++)
    {
        if (romanNum[i] == 'I')
            decimalNum++;
        if (romanNum[i] == 'V')
        {
            if (i > 0 && romanNum[i - 1] == 'I')
                decimalNum -= 2;
            decimalNum += 5;
        }
        if (romanNum[i] == 'X')
        {
            if (i > 0 && romanNum[i - 1] == 'I')
                decimalNum -= 2;
            decimalNum += 10;
        }
        if (romanNum[i] == 'L')
        {
            if (i > 0 && romanNum[i - 1] == 'X')
                decimalNum -= 20;
            decimalNum += 50;
        }
    }
    cout << decimalNum << endl;
    return decimalNum;
}




int main()
{
    string numerals;
    do{
        cout << "Enter roman numerals: ";
        cin >> numerals;

        romanType Rom;
        Rom.setRoman(numerals);
        Rom.romanToDecimal();

    } while (true);
    system("PAUSE");

}
```

**Sample output:**

> ```
> Enter roman numerals: IX
> 9
> Enter roman numerals: XI
> 11
> Enter roman numerals: XIX
> 19
> Enter roman numerals: XX
> 20
> Enter roman numerals: LVIII
> 58
> Enter roman numerals: LXXXVIII
> 88
> Enter roman numerals: LXVI
> 66
> Enter roman numerals: LXIV
> 64
> Enter roman numerals:
> ```

Comment: perhaps you should look at Enum

Answer (score 18, accepted):

- **Try not to use [`using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) and [`system("PAUSE")`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107705/systempause-why-is-it-wrong).**

  The former is okay for shorter programs or toy programs, or when used in local scope as opposed to global (such as within a function).

  The latter is best avoided as it is problematic while safer and more portable alternatives are in existence, such as `std::cin.get()`.  It's also non-portable and only works with Windows.
- In certain environments (or depending on personal preference), new user-defined types should be capitalized and objects should be lowercase.

  ```
  NewType objOfNewType;
  ```
- Prefer an initializer list here:

  ```
  NewType::NewType() : dataMember1(/* value */) {}
  ```

  Although this may not make a huge difference in your code, it's still good to know about it when writing larger programs.  It is best when initializing objects (especially when the arguments are of the same name) and *necessary* when initializing constants.
- As you're not using the destructor, you can leave it out.  The compiler will make one for you that does any of the default cleanup.
- You shouldn't do this in the class declaration:

  ```
  int decimalNum = 0;
  ```

  You should instead put that into the initializer list as mentioned above:

  ```
  // entries are separated by commas
  // can also be listed on separate lines
  className::className() : member1(0), member2(0) {}
  ```
- You have declared `printRoman()`, but have not defined it.  Better yet, overload `operator<<` for your class and leave out that empty declaration.

  Declare in header:

  ```
  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, Class const&);
  ```

  Define in source:

  ```
  std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Type const& obj)
  {
      return out << obj.typeMember;
  }
  ```

  Print it out:

  ```
  NewType objOfNewType;
  std::cout << objOfNewType;
  ```
- [`int` is not a good loop counter type here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181079/stringsize-type-instead-of-int):

  ```
  for (int i = 0; i < romanNum.length(); i++) {}
  ```

  `romanNum` is of type `std::string`, so you should use [`std::string::size_type`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t).  This will ensure that you can loop through *any* string size while not being limited by `int`'s size.

  Better yet, use its iterators instead (using a range-based `for`-loop in C++11):

  ```
  for (auto& iter : romanNum)
  {
      if (iter == 'I')
          decimalNum++;
  }
  ```

  Another alternative (if you don't have C++11 and cannot use the above):

  ```
  for (std::string::iterator = romanNum.begin(); iter != romanNum.end(); ++iter)
  {
      if (*iter == 'I')
          decimalNum++;
  }
  ```
- Prefer not to pass-by-value here:

  ```
  void romanType::setRoman(string troll)
  {
      romanNum = troll;
  }
  ```

  As you're not modifying `troll`, prefer to pass by constant reference (`const` and `&`).  This will avoid unneeded copying, thereby also increasing performance.  It's best only for non-native types (such as `std::string`), so disregard it for any of the [native ones](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types).

  Example (in different forms):

  ```
  void func(const std::string& str) {}
  ```

  ```
  void func(std::string const& str) {}
  ```
- `do-while` loops are usually considered less-readable than `while` loops.  However, you don't need a `while` loop here as that would require adding another user input before the loop.

  Instead, I'd recommend the "infinite loop" `for (;;)`:

  ```
  for (;;)
  {
      std::cout << "This message will print forever!\n";
      std::cout << "But please do end this eventually!\n\n";

      bool keepGoing = true;
      if (!keepGoing) break; // or return
  }
  ```

  As described, this will keep looping until the loop is ended (usually with a `break`, `return`, or `return X` if non-`void`).  You'll just need a conditional that will decide when the loop should end.
- Prefer to use variables as close in scope as possible:

  ```
  std::cout << "Input: ";
  int input;
  std::cin >> input;
  ```
- This is unneeded:

  ```
  romanType Rom;
  Rom.setRoman(numerals);
  ```

  You're invoking the default destructor (no arguments) while calling the mutator.

  Instead, the object should be constructed right away with `numerals`:

  ```
  romanType Rom(numerals);
  ```

  Beyond that, you won't need a mutator in your program.  They can also be bad for encapsulation, but that's another topic.  For now, focus on proper object construction while *only* using necessary implementations.  Keep your code as concise as possible.

  Note that my previous point about the initializer list was for example purposes.  In this case, you'll need to add an argument to the list.

  ```
  NewType::NewType(ArgType arg) : member1(arg) {}
  ```

  With this in place:

  ```
  NewType objOfNewType(5); // will compile
  NewType objOfNewType;    // will not compile
  ```

  In your program, the latter should still happen as the conversion process shouldn't work with no input given to the object.  You *can* also keep your existing default constructor, allowing the latter to still work.  But there may be no need for a default value if you want the user to give input.

Comment: Thanks! 
I realized it was an infinite loop, I did it intentionally because I was in the process of debugging something. The final program will ask the user if he/she wants to convert another numeral.

Comment: @Justin: That's fine.  It does still help to know about the different loops when putting them to real use.

Comment: You have suggested to do `for (;;) { ... if (!keepGoing) break; }` - if you do have a flag then wouldn't it be better to do `while(keepgoing) { ... }`?

Comment: @ChrisWue: Yes, perhaps.  This was mainly an example, and I assume the OP would just need a simple loop like this.

Answer (score 8):

Jamal has some good comments on general coding style. To address the other part of your question though, here's an alternative way of implementing the conversion from a Roman Numeral string to an integer which is more general and also cleaner IMO:

```
int fromRoman(const string& x) {
    auto first = crbegin(x);
    const auto last = crend(x);

    auto decimalDigitFromRoman = [&](char unit, char five, char ten) {
        int num = 0;
        for (; first != last && *first == unit; ++first) ++num;
        while (first != last && (*first == ten || *first == five)) {
            num += *first == ten ? 10 : 5;
            for (++first; first != last && *first == unit; ++first) --num;
        }
        return num;
    };

    int num = 0, pow = 1;
    for (auto syms : {"IVX", "XLC", "CDM"}) {
        num += decimalDigitFromRoman(syms[0], syms[1], syms[2]) * pow;
        pow *= 10;
    }

    return num;
}
```

[Live version](http://ideone.com/mhHldk).

This function handles the "standard" forms and also most of the ["alternative" forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals#Alternative_forms) described on the Wikipedia page.

[**Edited** to add explanation below]

There's a few observations that lead to the approach used here.

First, we can look at a Roman numeral as a special kind of decimal number where the 'digits' can be 0-n characters long and 'digits' of different powers are written with different symbols. So the number 321 (3x100 + 2x10 + 1x1) is written `CCC'XX'I` (3x100 + 2x10 + 1x1) (we don't write the separating `'`s). For the decimal digits 0-9 in least significant position the Roman numeral 'digits' are: `''(0)(an empty string), 'I'(1), 'II'(2), 'III'(3), 'IV'(4), 'V'(5), 'VI'(6), 'VII'(7), 'VIII'(8), 'IX'(9)`.

Second, 'digits' of each power of 10 are written the same way, just using different symbols. For each power of 10, we have a 'unit' symbol, a 'five' symbol and a 'ten' symbol. For 10^0 these are `I,V,X`, for 10^1 they are `X,L,C`, for 10^2, `C,D,M`. The system doesn't extend to 10^3.

Third, to parse a 'digit' forwards is tricky since we don't know for a given 'unit' symbol whether it is additive or subtractive without looking ahead (this is the problem that makes your code a bit tricky). Parsing backwards however we only need our previously seen context to interpret a symbol. If we see a 'five' or 'ten' symbol as our first symbol in a digit parsing backwards, subsequent 'unit' symbols for our current power are subtractive. Otherwise 'unit' symbols are additive until we hit a non-unit which marks the beginning of a subsequent 'digit'.

We can now understand the code above. The lambda `decimalDigitFromRoman` parses a single Roman numeral 'digit' given the symbols for 'unit', 'five' and 'ten' by stepping backwards through the string using a reverse iterator. The loop below the lambda parses a sequence of Roman numeral 'digits' by calling the lambda in sequence for each set of symbols and multiplying by the corresponding power of 10. The sum is the integer value of the Roman numeral string.

These rules as expressed in the code handle most of the edge cases automatically. Alternative forms like 'IIII' rather than 'IV' for 4 conveniently just fall out of the same rules when expressed appropriately. When we get to the 1000s we can just keep adding `M`s to the beginning of the number.